# Secure downloadable links

Tags: php

I am trying to offer authenticated users access to their reports. 
With the following code I create (depending on the logged in user) links like this:

```
echo "<a href = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/reports.php?file=XXXXXX.html'>Download Report Januar</a>";
```

Is this a save way to do it or are there any better ideas?

```
$dir = '/var/www/html/44ahj34k578adfhq238iqdn7VB/';
$type = 'text/html';


if(!empty($_GET['file']) && !preg_match('=/=', $_GET['file'])) {
    if ($_SESSION['username'] == 'XXXXX') {
            if(file_exists ($dir.$_GET['file']))     {
            makeDownload($_GET['file'], $dir, $type);
        } 
    } else {
        die("sorry, but you are not my type.");
    }
}


function makeDownload($file, $dir, $type) {

    header("Content-Type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
    readfile($dir.$file);
}

// File permissions:
    // drwxr-xr-x 2 www-data root      4096 Mar 27 10:12 44ahj34k578adfhq238iqdn7VB
    // -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data root 5056 Mar 27 10:13 XXXXX.html
```

Comment: So, the file is named after the username?

Comment: No, the XXX is only for anonymizing my data here.

Answer (score 0):

I notice a few security issues:

- You would want to provide the download links over https.
- You wouldn't want to link to any file on the basis of an essentially unchecked $_GET variable.
- You may want to further restrict a user to certain files rather than giving them open permission to download any file in the given directory.

Comment: I dont understand the last two comments. The files on the server belong to user "www-data". The user that actually authenticates and downloads the file (which will be many users) do not exist on the webserver. I will create for each user his download list. with ?file=filename.html. Of course these links could be guessed. Therefore users with no permissions will die with "sorry, your not my type". From my perspective the insecure part is the 44ahj34k578adfhq238iqdn7VB - directory which could be brute-force-attacked.

Comment: Anything coming through a $_GET variable is insecure.  I could for example attempt a directory traversal attack with something akin to the following: http://127.0.0.1:8080/reports.php?file=../../another_file.txt  Would your current implementation protect against it?  I believe it would pass your current preg_match regex.  Also, as I last mentioned, this would give users the ability to potentially download any file in that directory (which you may or may not find acceptable).

Comment: I would advise you not to take security by means of obscurity too seriously.  Consider that your site's users know each and every file/directory name on your server and ensure they still can't get to anything you don't want them to get to anyway.

Comment: It will be a good idea to add something like. if (user=authenticateduser) & (filename=filenameUserIsSupposedToDownload) then makeDownload. That's a good point.